# can't mount cdrom redhat enterprise 5 

Tags: linux, mount, compact-disc

This is what I get when I write this command:

```
$ mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
mount: block device /dev/cdrom is write-protected, mounting read-only 
UDDF-fs: No fileset found
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/cdrom, missing codepage or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog -try dmesg | tail or so
```

.......

and my fstab file is:

```
LABEL=/                /                   ex3     defaults             1 1
tmpfs                  /dev/shm            tmpfs   defaults             0 0
devpts                 /dev/pts            devpts   g id=4, mode=620    0 0
sysfs                  /sys                sysfs    defaults            0 0 
proc                   /proc               proc     defaults            0 0
LABEL=SWAP-sda2        swap                swap     defaukts            0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your disc is not listed in `/etc/fstab`, and the system appears to be guessing it's a UDF-format disc, which fails to mount.  Try mounting it as an ISO9660 disc:

```
mount -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
```

If that fails, run this command and update your question with the output:

```
dmesg | tail
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention WHAT cd you're trying to mount... and as ~quack mentioned it might be in a format other than the default format so you might have to specify it to mount.

Also the output you included gave you a hint and indeed it's appropriate to look at the output of dmesg and /var/log/messages as well, to see what's there and whether mount or the kernel left any clues in your error logs.

So please update this question with all of the above information... to help us help you.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with ~quack, also check whether you can read the disk using a different system.  Those error messages could easily be the result of a bad CD.